# Cypress request by exec curl

Tags: api, curl, cypress

I am writing test cases for tutorial using https://juice-shop.herokuapp.com/#/
I am trying to add user using api.
I wanted to add a user with curl, but it fails. It responds with success but new user is missing an email that is used to log in.

I can't find my mistake

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

const un = faker.internet.userName();
const domain = "@test.com";
const password = "qwerty123";
const api = "http://localhost:3000/api/Users/";
const sQuestion = "Your eldest siblings middle name?";
const sAnswer = "Joe";

describe('Login test cases suite', () => {
  describe('Login test cases - basic login cases', () => {
    it('New user - created by api', () => {
      _apiRegisterNewUser(`${un}_api${domain}`, password);
    });

    it('New user - created by curl', () => {
      _curlRegisterNewUser(`${un}_curl${domain}`, password);
    });
  });
});

export function _apiRegisterNewUser(email, password){
    cy.request(
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: api,
            body: {
                "email": email,
                "password": password,
                "securityQuestion": {
                    "id": "",
                    "question": sQuestion,
                    "createdAt": `${new Date().toISOString()}`,
                    "updatedAt": `${new Date().toISOString()}`,
                },
                "securityAnswer": sAnswer
            }
        }
    )
    .then((response) => cy.log(JSON.stringify(response)));
}

export function _curlRegisterNewUser(email, password){
    const com =
    `curl --request POST ${api} 
    --header "Content-Type: application/json"     
    --data-raw "{\"email\":\"${email}\",\"password\":\"${password}\",\"passwordRepeat\":\"${password}\",
    \"securityQuestion\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"question\":\"${sQuestion}\",\"createdAt\":\"\",\"updatedAt\":\"\",},
    \"securityAnswer\":\"${sAnswer}\"}"`
    cy.log(com);
    cy.exec(com).then((obj) => cy.log(obj.stdout));
}
```

Comment: Is it failing for `cy.request()` or `cy.exec()` or both? If it is failing for one and not the other, what's the value in testing this endpoint via both methods?

Comment: It is failing for cy.exec(). Just trying to figure out why curl won't work if ever this will be prefered solution.

Comment: I wouldn't spend too much effort trying to get the `cy.exec()` working until you know you need it if `cy.request()` works. `cy.request()` is a pretty important function for Cypress, so any major failing on that function would cause huge ripples across the Cypress ecosystem.